# How do I disable a wired network interface using Windows batch scripting?

Tags: networking, batch-file

How do I disable a wired network interface using Windows batch scripting?

What commands do I need to use?

Comment: My research indicates that this is not possible just using a batch file, you would need to use .NET code to talk to WMI or the Windows Script Host.

The following two articles should help get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cstcpipwmi.aspx?df=100&forumid=30597&exp=0&select=1564462

http://mcpmag.com/articles/2003/11/01/controlling-network-connections.aspx

Comment: Hi @Nick, welcome to Stack Overflow; you've just found out that our [FAQ states, "the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). :) Perhaps you've confused Stack Overflow with http://www.topcoder.com/ ? Stack Overflow is a repository of high-quality questions and answers. Had you posted the code you've already tried, and asked for help, you probably would have gotten better results. (Of course, @DaveRead's links look _very_ helpful.) You might also like to read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more advice on what we like to see in questions.

Comment: uhm, which version of windows are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To disable an interface in Windows type in the console :

```
netsh interface set interface "My Interface Name " DISABLE
```

and to enable it :

```
netsh interface set interface "My Interface Name " ENABLE
```